# pyqt5: Properly update QTreeView after data change on the database

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt5, qtreeview, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have a model-based QTreeView which is fed by a QSortFilterProxyModel.

I am displaying rows from the database here. With a double-click I am executing a modal QDialog to edit the data (the user can do CRUD operations like create new rows into my SQLite data base, updates, delete etc.).

On closing the edit-dialog the focus gets back to the underlying QTreeView.
Now I would like to refresh the changed data from the database.
One way to do this would be to build up my complete model and refetch all rows, but then the user-selected cell disappears and it is very slow and also the TreeView flickers (because I do some column adjustings concerning the width.)

Emiting dataChanged signal on the QSortFilterProxyModel somehow seems to do ... nothing.

Can I somehow tell my model to refresh or update the data, without fetching alls rows again?

full working code example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import sqlite3
import re

def _human_key(key):
    key = key.lower()
    key = key.replace("ä", "ae").replace("ö", "oe").replace("ü", "ue").replace("ß", "ss")
    parts = re.split(r'(\d*\.\d+|\d+)', key, re.IGNORECASE)
    return parts

class HumanProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def lessThan(self, source_left, source_right):
        data_left = source_left.data()
        data_right = source_right.data()
        if type(data_left) == type(data_right) == str:
            return _human_key(data_left) < _human_key(data_right)            
        return super(HumanProxyModel, self).lessThan(source_left, source_right)

class winMain(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    COL_ID, COL_NAME = range(2)    

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi()        

        # create and assign model
        self.model = self.createModel(self)

        proxy = HumanProxyModel(self)
        proxy.setSourceModel(self.model)
        self.treeView.setModel(proxy)

        # create db with some data                
        self.conn = self.setupDb()

        # format and sort the treeView
        self.treeView.setRootIsDecorated(False)
        self.treeView.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.treeView.sortByColumn(self.COL_ID, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.treeView.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.treeView.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.treeView.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)

        # display the main window
        self.show()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 QTreeView refresh problem demo")

        # add a data fetch button
        pbFetch = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        pbFetch.setText("Fetch data")
        pbFetch.move(350, 20)
        pbFetch.clicked.connect(self.on_pbFetch_clicked)

        # add a reset button
        pbReset = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        pbReset.setText("Reset")
        pbReset.move(450, 20)
        pbReset.clicked.connect(self.on_pbReset_clicked)

        # add QTreeView-Control
        self.treeView = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self)
        self.treeView.move(50, 100)
        self.treeView.resize(700, 300)
        self.treeView.doubleClicked.connect(self.on_treeView_doubleClicked)        

        self.resize(800,450)  # resize main window                       

    def on_pbFetch_clicked(self):        
        self.fetchData()

    def on_pbReset_clicked(self):
        print("on_pbReset_clicked() called.")
        self.reset()

    def setupDb(self):
        # create db and table
        con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
        con.execute("create table person(id int, name text)")                        
        # insert some example data
        con.execute("insert into person(id, name) values (1, 'anders')");
        con.execute("insert into person(id, name) values (2, 'Arachno')");
        con.execute("insert into person(id, name) values (3, 'Zabel')");
        con.execute("insert into person(id, name) values (4, 'Ötztürk')");
        con.execute("insert into person(id, name) values (5, 'de Hahn')");
        # commit the transaction
        con.commit()
        return con

    def reset(self):
        print("reset called.")
        self.model.beginResetModel()
        self.model.endResetModel()

    def fetchData(self):
        self.reset()

        cur = self.conn.cursor()
        sSql = "SELECT id, name FROM person"        
        rows = cur.execute(sSql)

        for row in rows:
            self.addPerson(self.model, row[0], row[1])

    def refresh_treeView(self):
        print("refresh_treeView() was called.")
        self.model.dataChanged.emit(QtCore.QModelIndex(), QtCore.QModelIndex())

    def createModel(self, parent):
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(0, 2, parent)
        model.setHeaderData(self.COL_ID, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "ID")        
        model.setHeaderData(self.COL_NAME, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Name")        
        return model

    def addPerson(self, model, personID, personName):
        model.insertRow(0)
        model.setData(model.index(0, self.COL_ID), personID)
        model.setData(model.index(0, self.COL_NAME), personName)

    def on_treeView_doubleClicked(self,index):
       row = index.row()
       ix = self.treeView.model().index(row, self.COL_ID)
       person_id = ix.data()
       print(f"id of double_clicked person: {person_id}")

       # create CRUD dialog for selected person
       self.disp_dlg_edit(person_id)       

    def disp_dlg_edit(self, person):        
       dlgEdit = QtWidgets.QDialog(self)

       lblId = QtWidgets.QLabel(dlgEdit)
       lblId.setText("ID:")       
       efId = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(dlgEdit)
       efId.setReadOnly(True)
       efId.setEnabled(False)
       efId.move(50, 0)

       lblName = QtWidgets.QLabel(dlgEdit)       
       lblName.setText("Name:")
       lblName.move(0, 25)
       efName = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(dlgEdit)       
       efName.move(50, 25)

       pbUpdate = QtWidgets.QPushButton(dlgEdit)
       pbUpdate.setText("Update")
       pbUpdate.move(200,0)
       pbUpdate.resize(100,50)              

       # fetch the data of given person
       cur = self.conn.cursor()
       sSql = "SELECT id, name FROM person WHERE id = ?"       
       cur.execute(sSql, (person,))
       result = cur.fetchone()
       person_id = result[0]
       efId.setText(str(person_id))
       person_name = result[1]
       efName.setText(person_name)

       pbUpdate.clicked.connect(lambda: self.update_person(person_id, efName.text()))

       dlgEdit.resize(300, 50)
       dlgEdit.exec_()

       self.refresh_treeView()

    def update_person(self, person_id, person_name):
        print(f"update_person({person_id}, {person_name}) called.")
        cur = self.conn.cursor()
        sSql = "UPDATE person set name=? WHERE ID=?"        
        cur.execute(sSql, (person_name,person_id,))
        self.conn.commit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = winMain()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Problem #1: Resetting the model does not work when clicking "Reset".
Problem #2: The treeView won't get reloaded on self.refresh_treeView()

Comment: 1) What do you expect to happen when calling the reset() function? 2) What do you expect to happen when calling the refresh_treeView() function?

Comment: 1.) Expectation: model gets resetted (empty). So, that when I click "FetchData" again, it will all build up from scratch. At the moment my fetch button appends the rows all the time.

2.) The whole treeView gets refreshed and reloads all data from the database, but e.g. without losing my currently selected cell.

Comment: The (1) I understand it but the (2) let's say that before calling refresh_treeView() the data is sorted with respect to the name and "" Arachno "is selected which is in the fourth row, but when reloading the data" Arachno "is in the 2nd row and in the fourth row is "Ötztürk" Which should be selected "Arachno" or "Ötztürk"?

Comment: Thanks for caring!
2: I had my cursor at the 4th row, so it should be the 4th row after the refresh, regardless of what data there is. Maybe some rows were inserted by the detail dialog or not, I just want to continue navigating in the treeView by the means of the cursor keys.
If i was in cell 4,3 (row 4, cell 3) then the selection/focus should stay here.
What else possibilities do I have? When I recreate the model every previous selection will be lost. Also it is slow. I expected hte "dataChanged" handler to just update the cells which have changed.. Or what does this handler exactly mean?

Comment: Got it from here... "From what I understand, this signal tells the view that "all the data has changed", so the view repaints everything. In the code that updates the underlying data, once all the data has been updated, I just call this method on the model, and the view automagically updates."

https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/48230-QTreeView-How-to-refresh-the-view

Comment: your datachanged has 2 errors: 1) The QModelIndex that you pass are invalid, 2) your model when refreshing would not use the database as source but the internal data of the same model, I recommend you check QSqlQueryModel or QSqlTableModel that if you interact with the database directly

Comment: If you want to reset the QStandardItemModel you must call clear(): change`self.model.beginResetModel()
        self.model.endResetModel()` to `self.model.clear()`

Comment: clear() destroys my model completely so that I cannot even see the columns anymore...

Comment: Is that that's what the reset does, maybe what you want is to eliminate all the rows, I think you use verbs without knowing what it means, so I recommend you ask what it means to you. If you just want to remove rows then delete row by row in a loop